# How to make call through Teams from c#

Tags: c#

I have created a bot using C# WPF. It has a button to make call.Previously if we click on that button it should redirect to Microsoft Teams and make a call using the phone number provided in the code, but now  we have to make a call to Group name instead of number in Teams.

Comment: Did you get solution to this?